# Retrieve html from textbox and display in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm retrieving a string from a textbox which will contain html eg `<html><head><body><div></div></body></head></html>`.

Basically i have got the content from the textbox, but cant get the popup to display like a html page.

In my jquery code i have

```
          var html = document.getElementById('<%=txtHtmlBody.ClientID%>').value;
          $(html).dialog();
```

At the moment the content looks like it is squashed into a small box, with a transparent background.
How can i get this to display like a html page in a popup?, any help is appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: in the HTML from textbox, order of HTML tags should be proper; it should be `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: may be your formed html elements is not the right way, try to make it looks like the following:<html><head></head><body><div>aaa</div></body></html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `div` that is filled with the contents of your textbox.

```
var myhtml = document.getElementById('<%=txtHtmlBody.ClientID%>').value;
$('#mydiv').html(myhtml);
$('#mydiv').dialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add one empty element in your page.

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

so, put value of field into your element, and show this:

```
$('#dialog').html($('#<%=txtHtmlBody.ClientID%>').val());
$('#dialog').dialog();
```